# audacity not starting

Tags: sound, 15.04, dell, audacity

When I try to start audacity all I can see is a blank window

[image]

and when I start from the terminal I get

```
$ audacity 
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM     cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
10:31:28: Debug: DirManager: Created new instance.
Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1736
Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir,     &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1904
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->capture, alsaApi,     inParams, StreamDirection_In, NULL != callback )' failed in     'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2171
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi,     inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback,     streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c',     line: 2840
10:31:29: Debug: PortAudio stream error creating device list: ALSA:HDA     Intel PCH: ALC3235 Analog (hw:1,0): Device unavailable
Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in     'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
```

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 on a Dell Latitude E5450.